# GKE Autopilot: Detect and handle OOM errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We are running both a CronJob and other Jobs in GKE Autopilot.  If a given job happens to fail due to lack of memory, we want the CronJob to detect this condition and raise the memory limit for the job and retry it.  I'm looking for advice on the best way to do this.

My attempts so far involve listing all the pods for the job and checking each one to see if it was terminated with a reason of "OOMKilled".  Unfortunately, the pods might be automatically deleted before the CronJob wakes up and looks (it runs every 5 minutes).  I had thought to check the events log, but the only evidence I can see of a killed pod is if a "created" event was logged for a pod but not a "deleted" event.  But it appears this symptom can have other causes as well so it is not a reliable indicator of running out of memory.